# Array of words remove by length?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Filter array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910301/php-filter-array)

I have a PHP array containing strings of random length.

I want need to keep those that are less than 6 characters long.

How can I do this?

Solution:  I used this which is like Fardjad's answer:

```
$counter=0;
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    if (strlen($value) >=$maxlength) {
unset($myarray[$counter]);
   }
 $counter++;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Have you had a look at the [PHP array function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)? Straightforward idea: Iterate over the array, test the length of the string, if it is longer than 6, delete the element or if it is smaller, add it to a new array.

Comment: I am hoping there is a PHP function that I don't know about to do this.  I have an idea for a long way to do it,but I am hoping someone will tell a way to do it that is shorter.

Comment: You have an idea of how to do it?  Then tell us what you've tried.

Comment: I didn't try it, just the long way of a foreach loop checking the length of every point in the array and removing the bad ones individually.

Comment: Are you trying to implement some std algorithm?If not the way is rather simple.......

Comment: `array_filter($strings, function($string) {return !isset($string[5]);});`

Comment: @David19801 The point is that this site isn't: Ask question, get free code! People are here to help out other people who have shown that they've made an effort to solve their problem but hit a road block somewhere. There are plenty of sites where you can hire someone to write code for you with specifications only -- but that isn't here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key=>&$value) {
    if (strlen($value) > 6) {
        unset($yourArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the & sign a special way of using key value pairs here?  Sorry, I am not good with arrays...

Comment: @David19801 `&$value` is a reference (you can just ignore it in this snippet), see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php for more information about references.

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php
$array_with_random_strings = <Your array here>; 

function less_than_six($word) {
    return strlen($word) < 6; 
}

$your_desired_array = array_filter($array_with_random_strings, "less_than_six"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
<?php
    $random = array('1234','12345','123456','1234657');
    for($i=0, $j=0 ; $i<count($random) ; $i++)
        if(strlen($random[$i])<6){
            $lessthan6[$j] = $random[$i];
            $j = $j+1;
        }
?>
```