# php Multiple Key Value Filter with an or statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, filter

I have been searching everywhere for this and i not sure something like this can be done. but i hope some one can point me in the right direction.

I am getting a multidimensional array from mysql. I need to filter this array, so i am using the following code

```
$filter = new MultipleKeyValueFilter(array(
    'sex' => '1',
  'age' => '4'

));

print_r(array_filter($ads_array, array($filter, 'filter')));
```

I have the filter values set as you can see, but i need these values to do something like this

```
$filter = new MultipleKeyValueFilter(array(
    'sex' => '1' or '0',
  'age' => '4'

));

echo "Filtered by multiple fields\n";
print_r(array_filter($ads_array, array($filter, 'filter')));
```

As you can see in the code above, i want to keep both of them in the array. The field can have 1 or 0 and both is good. But when i try this i get nothing. So it seems i can't use or and also not ||.

How should i go about this issue. How can i have it accept both values as a good result?

The other pieces of code i am using are these

```
class MultipleKeyValueFilter implements Filter {
    protected $kvPairs;

    public function __construct($kvPairs) {
        $this->kvPairs = $kvPairs;
    }

    public function filter($item) {
        $result = true;

        foreach ($this->kvPairs as $key => $value) {
            if ($item[$key] !== $value)
                $result &= false;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}


class MultipleKeyComparator implements Comparator {
    protected $keys;

    public function __construct($keys) {
        $this->keys = $keys;
    }
```

I hope i make a little sense here.

Comment: Related: [Filter out all rows that do not match multiple rules across four different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4910301/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because when you say:

> ```
> 'sex' => '1' or '0',
> ```

that gets interpreted an in-line conditional and you wind up with

```
'sex' => true,
```

If you want your `MultipleKeyValueFilter` to do what you want, you're going to have to change both your criteria array and your filter class. You'll want to pass something like:

```
'sex' => ['1', '0'], //1 and 0 are acceptable values
```

and rewrite your comparator to something like:

```
public function filter($item) {
    foreach ($this->kvPairs as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value) {
            $match = false;

            foreach($value as $v) {
                $match = ($item[$key] === $v);
                if($match) {
                    break; //If we find one match in our array, we can stop looking
                }
            }

        } else {
            $match = ($item[$key] === $value);
        }

        if(!$match) {
            return false; //Any failure to match can stop immediately
        }
    }

    return true; //If we get here, then we didn't fail to match any criteria
}
```