# Filter out array values that do not contain a specified substring

Tags: php, arrays, substring, filtering, array-filter

I would like to know how can I filter an array to remove values that do not contain a specified string?

Example:

```
$array = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'];
$to_search = "uary"; // not case sensitivity
$result = somefunction($array, $to_search );
print_r($result);
```

The expected output is:

```
$result = ['January', 'February'];
```

I hope to use the most efficient and fastest way in searching among the arrays because the array that I might use contains at least 100 items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Filter array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910301/php-filter-array)

Comment: Sorry for me this is hard but the question would be which among the answers have the best benchmark? :)

Comment: do not worry much about performance. 100 items is nothing.

Comment: @yivi when should I worry? if it is 1000? or more? sorry I'm just curious but all of their answers are good for me just having a hard time to choose :)

Comment: And besides, _benchmark_ questions are not really good questions, since you should be able to build your own test for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/728930)**

You should choose [array_filter](http://fr.php.net/array_filter) function.
e.g.

```
$to_search = "uary"; // not case sensitivity
$array = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April');

$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($to_search ) {
 if (stripos($item, $to_search ) !== false) {
    return true;
 }
return false;
});
```

and to get and display your array, use the `var_dump`

```
var_dump($result);
```

Please try with this and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](https://eval.in/728945)**

```
$array = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April');
$to_search = "uary"; // not case sensitivity
$result = somefunction($array, $to_search );
print_r($result);
function somefunction($array, $to_search ){
    $a=array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        if (strpos($value, $to_search) !== false) {
            $a[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}

//Output
Array ( [0] => January [1] => February )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
function search_string_arr($arr, $to_search)
{
    $temp = [];
    foreach ($arr as $index => $string) {
        if (strpos($string, $to_search) !== false) {
            $temp[] = $string;
        }
    }
    return $temp;
}
$array     = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April');
$to_search = "uary"; // not case sensitivity
$arr = search_string_arr($array, $to_search);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Here is working demo [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74e39a977081bbde0633b8f3abc3bc62ad283236).

Answer (score 0):

From PHP8, you can use `array_filter()`, arrow function syntax, and `str_contains()` to concisely execute the desired filtration.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/r2Rcu))

```
var_export(
    array_filter($array, fn($v) => str_contains($v, $to_search))
);
```

With arrow function syntax, you don't need to leverage `use()` to invite `$to_search` into the custom function scope.